# Git/Github: How to transfer changes from one repository to another

Tags: git, github, version-control

Steps I have made:

1. I found a project in Github that I thought I could contribute.
2. I cloned it directly without creating a Fork.
3. I made my changes
4. Now that I want to upload my changes, I realized that I was not working in a fork.

How do I manage to upload my changes to the repository of the fork in order to do a Pull Request from the fork to the original repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another [git remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) with your repo URL and then push to it:

```
git remote add myrepo git@github.com:your-user/repo
git push myrepo master
```

You can push to *master* or to any remote branch you want.

Both repos should share the root tree, which is the case if you have forked it.

As an alternative, you could change your current *origin* remote and then push normally to *origin*:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:your-user/repo
git push origin master
```